# Ubuntu 10.10: Email Server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

Let's assume I know nothing about mailservers or Linux/Ubuntu.

I want to set up a mail server that will easily allow me to add emails with different domains and connect with various email clients via pop/imap.

What is the best way to set this up? I believe I have postfix running, but that's as much as I know. :/ I'm a noob at this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix will allow you to deliver emails to different domains, and to send emails.  You should install something like Dovecot or Courier to handle the pop/IMAP.

Read the Ubuntu documentation for postfix [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto).  Important things to pay attention to are the type of inbox (maildir vs mbox) and your authentication (Dovecot SASL vs Cyrus SASL; flat file vs sql db).

You'll want to use the Postfix virtual mailbox delivery agent to deliver mail from separate domains to non-system accounts.  Here is an example configuration to add to your main.cf file (/etc/postfix/main.cf) for the domain "example.com":

`virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com ...more domains...` 
`virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts` 
`virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox` 
`virtual_minimum_uid = 100` 
`virtual_uid_maps = static:5000` 
`virtual_gid_maps = static:5000` 
`virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`

In the third line there's `virtual_mailbox_maps =`.  This is the file that holds the mapping between the email address and where the email is stored.  You'll need to add the following to your vmailbox file (/etc/postfix/vmailbox):

`info@example.com    example.com/info` 
`sales@example.com   example.com/sales/` 
`# Comment out the entry below to implement a catch-all.` 
`# @example.com      example.com/catchall` 
`...virtual mailboxes for more domains...`

In the seventh line of main.cf there's a line with `virtual_alias_maps =` that maps the alias names you might use.  Add the following to your virtual file (/etc/postfix/virtual):

`postmaster@example.com postmaster`

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how to add emails and such.

Comment: There's a lot to learn in running your own email server.  You should read the documentation and then come back and ask your specific questions.  I don't use a GUI for postfix, so I don't know how much use I can be there.  I've edited my answer to provide an example of virtual mailboxes so that you don't have to map each email address to a system user.  That should help guide you.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use a GUI and if so what are some good ones? (Helpful edit)

Comment: A GUI would be helpful to teach you most of what goes into a Postfix setup.  At some point, you'll learn to do this through the configuration files for maximum control.  Go here for a list of useful GUI tools: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/postfixweb.htm